# How to fire a panel scroll event when a mouse cursor is on a combobox belonging to the panel

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mouseevent

I've developed a Windows form program using C#.

I added a panel and a combobox which belongs to the panel.
The vertical mouse scroll event has occurred when a mouse cursor was not pointing to the combobox. But when the mouse cursor pointed to the combobox the vertical mouse scroll event has not occurred.

I think that I made a mistake while configuring the mouse event for the combobox.

Could you let me know which property of the combobox has to be configured? What event shall I configure?

Answer (score 0):

When the cursor points to Combobox, the focus will be on Combobox, so the Panel's "mouse scroll event" will not be triggered.

Maybe you can bind the method to both `MouseWheel` event of Panel and Combobox.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // subscribe to MouseWheel
    panel1.MouseWheel += MouseWheelMethod;
    comboBox1.MouseWheel += MouseWheelMethod;
}

int i = 0;

private void MouseWheelMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i++); // test
}
```